# Does AWS API Gateway websocket need load balancer to handle traffics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

I am building a chat application and I've decided to go with AWS API Gateway websocket & lambda functions. Do I really need load balancer to handle the traffic or lambda will take care of its own.

Thanks,

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you don't need that?

Comment: Yes Marcin. I am aware of that lambda function can scale automatically by itself when traffic increase. but I am not sure thats enough to handle real time chat application where hundreds of users sending requests at the same time. So If you explain in details that would be really helpful to decide the approach. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Api gateway and lambda scale automatically. You don't have to explicitly create any load balancers for that.